# How to get backup of the file replacing that file using command

Tags: linux, command, backup

While replacing the folder, the file which has been changed should get backup, then it should get replace.Is any script or command for this work in linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync for this case. Specify an --compare-dest so files which are different in the locations gets copied there.

First try an dry run to check your config:

```
rsync -aHxv --progress --dry-run --compare-dest=backup-change-files/ folder1/ folder2/
```

If all is good run it with:

```
rsync -aHxv --progress  --compare-dest=backup-change-files/ folder1/ folder3/
```

Please try it with some copied data for testing first.